# If else in foreach

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array `arr=[{key: 'first'},{key: 'second'} ...]`, I want to go through that array and check if an element with a specific key exist and do something.

```
  arr.forEach(element => {
     if(element.key === 'first') {
        // do something
     } else { 
        // do something else
     }

     if(element.key === 'second') {
        // do something
     } else { 
        // do something else
     }         
  });
```

The thing is that when it goes through array, it first sees `'first'` and it goes through `if()` statement, but it also goes through `else()` statement of `'second'` item because it did't find it, and so it does when `foreach` goes through other items in array. I don't know how to make it to go through array one time and set `if() else()` appropriately. So when it finds `'first'` I want it just to do `if()` of that item and not `else()` of others. I hope you understand. Thanks in advance!

Edit: My logic behind this code is that when I call database and find that array if there is no `'firstExercise'` in that array, then it should add it to that db (I am using firebase so in `else()` I am calling db to create that exercise), and if there is`'firstExercise'` in array do nothing. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Edit2: Here is my original code:

```
  res.forEach(element => {
     if (this.numbOfFinished === 1) {
       if (element.key === 'firstExercise') {
           console.log('has')            
      } else {
        awardName = 'firstExercise'
        this.homeService.addAward(this.userId, awardName).then(() => {
          this.awardName = 'firstExercise';
         this.awarded = true;
         });
       }
     }
   });


     if (this.numbOfFinished === 5) {
       if (element.key === 'fifthExercise') {
           console.log('has')            
      } else {
        awardName = 'fifthExercise'
        this.homeService.addAward(this.userId, awardName).then(() => {
          this.awardName = 'fifthExercise';
         this.awarded = true;
         });
       }
     }
   });
```

Comment: How about a `switch`?

Comment: Or, use a `return true` to continue.

Comment: so if it is supposed to onlu go into the else than why are you seem like you should be using an `else if`

Comment: Or `else if` statements.

Comment: you are using multipe `if` and it goes in else for second `if` try to manage in singe if or use `switch`

Comment: So what exactly is the `else` for? You want the `else` branch to only execute if, e.g., `'first'` *wasn't found in the list at all*?

Comment: So what's the point of having those `else`s in the first place? What you describe is completely expected behavior. What are you actually trying to do? What's in your `else` blocks? A better solution might be `if (arr.some(e => e.key === 'first')) ...`

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited to question to how you what I really want

Comment: Then you don't go through the array and *do something for each item*, but you *test whether the item is in the array* and then do something based on that.

Comment: Yes, I thought that, just to find that item in array. I should do `find()` then?

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to create arrays which makes the relation between a key and functions. So I can iterate and call the proper one.

What I like in this solution instead of using a `switch/case` or `if/else` forest is that you can apply automatic treatments and that you can easily make it to evolve.

```js
const mapKeyFunc = [{
  key: 'first',

  func: async(x) => {
    console.log('Do something for key first');

    // here you can perform an async request and modify `this`
  },
}, {
  key: 'second',

  func: async(x) => {
    console.log('Do something for key second');

    // here you can perform an async request and modify `this`
  },
}];

const doStuff = async(arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    const mapElement = mapKeyFunc.find(x => x.key === arr[i].key);

    await mapElement.func.call(this, arr[i]);
  }
};

const arr = [{
  key: 'first',
  otherStuff: 0,
}, {
  key: 'second',
  otherStuff: 42,
}];

doStuff(arr).then(() => {}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

---

If you don't need the treatment to be synchronous, here we have an asynchronous method

```js
const mapKeyFunc = [{
  key: 'first',

  func: async(x) => {
    console.log('Do something for key first');

    // here you can perform an async request and modify `this`
  },
}, {
  key: 'second',

  func: async(x) => {
    console.log('Do something for key second');

    // here you can perform an async request and modify `this`
  },
}];

const doStuff = async(arr) => {
  await Promise.all(arr.map(x => mapKeyFunc.find(y => y.key === x.key).func.call(this, x)));
};

const arr = [{
  key: 'first',
  otherStuff: 0,
}, {
  key: 'second',
  otherStuff: 42,
}];

doStuff(arr).then(() => {}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one option out of them to be executed (and then exiting out of the function), you could use `else if` statements like so:

```
arr.forEach(element => {
  if(element.key === 'first') {
     // do something
  } else if(element.key === 'second') {
     // do something
  } else { 
     // do something else
  }         
});
```

This will do pretty much exactly what you expect. If `element.key == 'first'`, it'll do block one. Else, if `element.key == 'second'`, it'll do block two. Else, it'll do block three.

Comment: You sniped me -- it wasn't there when I was writing my answer.

Comment: I was assuming that you have already started writing your answer and did not see that I finished it earlier, this is why I did not downvote your answer, as I think you had the very same idea independently from me, even though you finished writing it 4 minutes later. So, the most elegant thing I could do was merely pointing out that I had given the same answer slightly earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge the `if` statements like this:

```
  arr.forEach(element => {
     if(element.key === 'first') {
        // do something
     } else if(element.key === 'second') {
        // do something else
     }         
  });
```

`element.key` has a single value in each iteration and you therefore need a single level of conditioning.